# How common are expander graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

A more formal way to phrase my question is: given a fixed $d$, a small constant $\epsilon$, and an integer $n$. How large is the smallest $d$-regular $\epsilon$-expander with at least $n$ vertices? I presume it is linear in $n$?